# AngularJS Printing text if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I am trying to print text on the page in a `<h1>` tag depending on whether a check box is checked or not.

```
$scope.EmailMe = function(email) {
    if($scope.emailchecked == 1) {
        $scope.test = "emailSent";
    } else {
        $scope.test = "nothing";
    }
    }
```

HTML is :

```
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="emailchecked" ng-change="EmailMe(1)">
        <h1> @{{test}} </h1>
```

I have the text printing but the checkbox is not being checked. or allowing for change please help :)

Comment: do you want to have `0` & `1` value in the checkbox?

Comment: @NishanthMatha the checkbox can now be checked :). But unfortunately the text is no longer printing. I know my code is messy im new to angular, is there a better approach to check if something is checked?

Comment: @PankajParkar I know that may be missing but I'm unsure of how it should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-true-value` & `ng-false-value`, so that will give you `1`/`0` value based on selection.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="emailchecked"
  ng-true-value="1" 
  ng-false-value="0" 
  ng-change="EmailMe(emailchecked)">
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aKLnSm7W9VVJiNmDRWyz?p=preview)

Even if you don't use `ng-true-value`, but that would not kept you model value to 0/1. By default checkbox value is true/false.

Comment: Thank you alot, + 1 for teaching me inbuilt angularJS function that I did not know

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="emailchecked" ng-change="EmailMe()">
    <h1> @{{test}} </h1>
  </body>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.EmailMe = function() {
    if($scope.emailchecked == 1) {
        $scope.test = "emailSent";
    } else {
        $scope.test = "nothing";
    }

    };

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EfIMMn7Be7QL258aUiXW

and in your code you are changing the `emailchecked` which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change if(email = 1)  to if(email == 1). One equal is missing